# row indices (start + span) mustn't exceed the row count exception in android

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

My layout was working fine when suddenly it started to gave me this exception:

`row indices (start + span) mustn't exceed the row count`

even if I start over and create my layout again I still get this error.

Here's my code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="sign up"
        android:id="@+id/textView_sign_up_header"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textColor="#FFF"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:rowCount="6"
            android:useDefaultMargins="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_columnSpan="2"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/editText_first_name"
                        android:hint="name"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:textDirection="rtl"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/global_edit_text_size"/>

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/editText_last_name"
                        android:hint="last name"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:textDirection="rtl"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/global_edit_text_size"/>

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </GridLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have no idea what went wrong, Because I had the exact same code and it was working fine

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your columCount or rowCount is not enough.

Answer (score -2):

**Re: Maybe your columCount or rowCount is not enough.**
That is exactly what the problem was, and had I not thrown a big try/catch block around all of my code in MainActivity I would have just got a crash without any error messages